# nothing happening while decoding json data

Tags: php, json, jsondecoder, jsonencoder

Im trying to decode the following json data, 
NOTE, the data has a weird attribute a **'\'** in front of each key.

```
{"data":"{\"product_data\":{\"LXR12-3\":0,\"GXPI01\":1,\"LXR12-1\":1,\"LXR12-2\":1},\"access_token\":\"1M6opdQlMXygxowkn8uOgsEYNUGcXKF4UcuMX0fzwpxmZT4Hn7\",\"intent\":\"okay\",\"update\":false}"}
```

## PHP

```
$jsonRaw = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents('RAW.txt', $jsonRaw);
$data = json_decode($jsonRaw,true);
file_put_contents('DATA.txt', $data);
$access_token = $data['access_token'];  
$intent = $data['intent'];  
$isEdit = $data['update'];  


$text = "access_token : $access_token | intent : $intent | edit : $isEdit";
file_put_contents('GOT_DATA.txt', $text);
```

The output of the 'GOT_DATA' file is,

```
access_token :  | intent :  | edit :
```

The output for the DATA.txt file is,

```
{"product_data":{"LXR12-3":0,"GXPI01":1,"LXR12-1":1,"LXR12-2":1},"access_token":"1M6opdQlMXygxowkn8uOgsEYNUGcXKF4UcuMX0fzwpxmZT4Hn7","intent":"okay","update":false}
```

The values are not begin stored into the variables? What exactly am i doing wrong here? 
and does anyone know
why the recvied json have a '\' in front?

## UPDATE

After changing the source of the JSON i managed to return it like (RAW.txt),

```
{"data":{"product_data":{"LXR12-2":0,"GXPI01":0,"LXR12-3":1,"LXR12-1":1},"access_token":"1M6opdQlMXygxF4UcuMX0fzwpxmZT4Hn7","intent":"okay","update":false}}
```

Now the outputs for the files for DATA.txt,

```
Array
```

It just says 'Array' Why???

Comment: You have `{"data":"...` - that final quote means that the value you stored in the data property was stringified first, so data contains a string not an object.  I imagine you wanted that to be an object, so whatever code is posting this to php, it's encoding the data property as a string first - make it stop.

Comment: Note you've just posted your access token. There doesn't appear to be any other identifying information in the post, but you probably want to change/revoke it immediately anyway.

Comment: @James im going through my code now, will update you asap.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I changed some letters so it'll be okay :P

Comment: @James I updates the question and fixed what you mentioned eariler, but now all i get is 'Array' as outputafter decoding

Comment: Now you have product_data as the only property of data.  So $data["intent"] won't work, it would have to be $data["product_data"]["intent"]

Comment: OMG, how did i miss that. It works now! Thanks